# Showing $\|f\|_{\infty}= \|g\|_{\infty}$ if $f=g$ almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a measurable space $(X, A, \mu)$, define $\mathcal{L}^{\infty} =\{f \text{ is measurable}, \exists M>0, |f(x)| < M \space \mu \space \text{almost surely}\}$, $\sim$ is a equivalent relations on $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$, $f \sim g$ iff$f=g$ almost surely, $L^{\infty}= \mathcal{L}^{\infty} /\sim$, $\|f\|_{\infty}=\inf \{M>0; |f(x)| <M \space \mu \space\text{almost surely} \}$

I would like to show if $f=g$, $\mu$ almost surely, then $\|f\|_{\infty}= \|g\|_{\infty}$

**I want to show two infimum equals to each other, one way to do is by showing the sets where we calculate the infimum are equal.** (Is it right? I think it is a strong condition for showing $\inf = \inf$ )

So take a $M$, such that $|f(x)| <M$ almost surely, $\{|g(x)| > M\} \subset \{g(x) \neq f(x)\} \cup \{|f(x)| > M\}$, so $|g(x)| <M$ almost surely. By symmetricity, we have $\{M>0; |f(x)| <M \space \mu \space\text{almost surely} \}= \{M>0; |g(x)| <M \space \mu \space\text{almost surely} \}$, so the infimums. Am I right proving thin way?

Comment: The proof looks fine to me, except for a minute correction that you should have a $\le$ instead of $<$.

Comment: Yes, It is a typo. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Looks good. But in general, it will not work to say $\inf(A)= \inf(B)$ since $A= B$ (because $\inf(A)= \inf(B)$ may also happen even if $A \cap B = \emptyset!$).

Comment: So you mean $A=B$, then $\inf(A)=\inf(B)$, but the inverse will be wrong.